# ASP.NET WEB API 2 installed in Sub-Domain: Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, owin, access-token, access-denied

I have a hybrid MVC 5 and Web Api 2 application.
Users get a bearer token to authenticate.

On `localhost:123456` and `somedomain.com` it runs as expected.

But when I deployt it to **the same** VPS/IIS and run it on a subdomain like `app.someotherdomain.com`, then suddenly all controllers with an `[Authorize]` attribute give an"Authorization has been denied for this request."

I have read many suggestions, so I also tried to add a default Claims role to see of that made a difference, but still the same error.

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{

    // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

    var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
                {
                    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
                };

    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthServerOptions);

}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // add global authorization filter
        config.Filters.Add(new ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute());

        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
    }
}
```

**SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.cs**

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        string userId;

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
            userId = user.Id;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        var roles = userManager.GetRoles(userId);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId));

        context.Validated(identity);
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }

    #region Methods

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    #region Methods

    public IUnityContainer Container;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AutoMapperBootstrapper.Initialize();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This message may appear in several cases, for instance, when there is an [Authorize] attribute, but the only enabled authentication in IIS is 'Anonymous Authentication'.